# How to get access to Macbook/recover data there?

Tags: networking, macos, mac, macbook, authentication

I can't find the account on the login screen anymore that I use to login to my work MAC. The data on my mac is very critical, and I might miss several deadlines if the data is not recovered.

The account I use to login is a network account, but that is not showing up anymore apparently because I manually changed the system time and (since network accounts use Kerberos) laptop's relationship with Domain Controller is severed. Now, I need to log back in to reestablish the relationship. I have exhausted all the possible admin accounts that were suggested.

What are my options here? Could an internet recovery help? Is there a way to change system time/update timezone settings without logging in? Could create a bootable installer be an option? Please help, it is vital to get the data.

Comment: Sounds like you need to speak to your IT department. Corporate support issues are off-topic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is a technical issue though. I have IT Dept engineers in my confidence but we all seem to find so solution other than letting the laptop(and the data) go here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:-

Boot the Mac into the macOS Recovery system by pressing Command (⌘) and R together at power up. (See - [Mac startup key combinations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255)).

When in MacOS Recovery goto the `Utilities` menu and select `Terminal`. (see [About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314))

In the terminal window change the system date/time using the date command with this format:-

```
date -u {month}{day}{hour}{minute}{year}
```

e.g. for December 4th 2019 11:36

```
date -u 1204103619
```

as described in detail in [Changing system date from Terminal – OS X recovery](https://bensmann.no/changing-system-date-from-terminal-os-x-recovery/)